# Accessing serialized form data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, serialization

I'm trying to avoid the pesky page reload and trying to dynamically reload a div when the user submits a form. However, although the data does get passed successfully and the output of the serialized data is correct, I am not able to access these in the PHP file.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var submiting = false;

    function submitmyforum()
    {
        alert($('#filter_form').serialize());
        if (submiting == false)
        {
            submiting  = true;
            $.ajax({
                type:   'post',
                url:    'index.php',
                data:   $('#filter_form').serialize(),
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    $('#clublist').html($(data).filter('#clublist').contents());
                    alert('submitted');
                    submiting  = false;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Still working ..");
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
        echo "Location was set";
    }
?>
```

Now, in my HTML I have multiple checkbox options with the name = "location[]". Besides, the web site is working fine with the traditional page reload technique in which the form submits the values to the same page via POST method.

So I am kind of sure that there is nothing wrong at the HTML front. I am awaiting a solution.

Comment: you can access it by `$_POST` variable..

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump( $_POST )` to see what you got

Comment: I'm trying exactly that but I dont get the desired output.

Comment: I'm trying exactly that but I dont get the desired output. I tried the var_dump as well. But no output. Actually, the moment i click on the button, i see the 2 alerts alright, the div gets reloaded but it appears empty, an echo "hi" doesnt get displayed either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get data as post then you should use:

```
serializeArray() instead of serialize()
```

Because `serializeArray()` creates an array which is not a JSON array. I suggest you to change it in your code and try to access the data as `$_POST`.

Comment: I tried that it isn't working. Should i be moulding my php into a separate function altogether and then mention the function in the url? I doubt if the data is really getting passed on to the php code. How can i check that?

Comment: you can alert the data to check what kind of data you got in response and in your php page echo/print_r the variable/array and end it with exit.